# I have an imagebutton which is in a datalist. Onclick, the event for the image button is not firing. How can I get it to fire?

Tags: asp.net

```
<%@ Page  Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Sablon.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Cevaplar.aspx.cs" Inherits="Cevaplar"  %>
<asp:DataList ID="datalistsoru" runat="server" >
 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" ImageUrl="~/resimler/yukariok.jpg" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

and cs code is here

```
  protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

and I click the img button it has errors which contains
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  but doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put your Page_Load() code in if(!IsPostBack) condition, if you haven't. That solves the problem for me in most cases.
Or you can try with the ItemCommand event of the DataList wich fires when Command event is generated within the list.